# Make a logger to skip the root section in logback

Tags: java, logback, appender

I have several loggers defined and a root section with several appenders, something like:

```
  <logger name="X" level="debug"/>
  <logger name="Y" level="trace"/>

  <logger name="Z" level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="ALERTS-SYSLOG" />
  </logger>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="BUFFER"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
  </root>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the logger named Z to go **only** to the ALERTS-SYSLOG appender and not all the ones defined in the root section. Is that possible only with configuration on the XML file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an entry in the XML file explicitly for logger Z and with the ALERTS_SYSLOG appender and set the additvity flag to false.

Comment: Thanks. My post was supposed to have some examples but somehow they were lost.

Answer (score 25):

See logback documentation for [appender additivity](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#additivity) and for [additivity configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#overrridingCumulativity). In short, the Z logger should be configured as:

```
<!-- set the additivity attribute of the Z logger to false -->
<logger name="Z" level="warn" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="ALERTS-SYSLOG" />
</logger>
```